# django-cms TemplateDoesNotExist INHERIT

Tags: django-templates, django-cms

I installed django-cms and configured it according to the documentation.
The site comes up, but when I try to add a page I get an error:
TemplateDoesNotExist: INHERIT

I don't specify INHERIT as a template anywhere.  It's finding my template directory ok, but I have no template named INHERIT and I don't know where that request is coming from.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check your TEMPLATES settings.

Looking through the source code:

By default template for a page set here:

```
TEMPLATE_DEFAULT = ... get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')[0][0]
```

Source:

> https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/pagemodel.py#L41
>   https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/pagemodel.py#L77

And looking through source code in `utils/conf.py`. A template named 'INHERIT' is added to list of available templates. And it looks like you own templates are not registered correctly and therefore the 'INHERIT' template is first item in the list.

> https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/utils/conf.py#L99
>   https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/utils/conf.py#L136

Comment: I dont' have CMS_TEMPLATES_DIR set, is it ok to be the same as my TEMPLATES_DIR?

Comment: How do I get my templates registered?  I haven't seen how to do that.  I have my settings file with TEMPLATE_DIRS set correctly - it is looking there for 'INHERIT'
I have the filesystem and app_directories loaders installed.  Should I disable the app_directory loader (as I am not using that feature I don't believe).
Then I have a myriad of TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS which I don't believe have anything to do with registering the templates.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Got it - I think i misplaced my CMS_TEMPLATES command.  It's not in my settings file (?)
Thanks for your help.  I would have voted up your answer - but I don't have enough 'status' to do so.  If you could vote up my question - I could vote up your answer.  --thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had failed to set the CMS_TEMPLATES as directed in the tutorial.  (Actually, I had - but gremlins removed it).